# React bootstrap Nav bar not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I already did npm install on react-bootstrap and do

import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem, MenuItem, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';

at the beginning, but I got this error
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , 
with inverse which is in < Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect >

Here's my code for render method in react component [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eKUS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to pass the property "inverse" into a props :

`<Navbar bsStyle="inverse" collapseOnSelect>`

You can check the available props there : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navigation

Hope it helps :)

Dylan